# Group table rows jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having a scenario in which I need to group the rows of a HTML table.
The table is as follows:

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;" cellpadding="5" width="500px">
  <tr>
    <td>No.</td>
    <td>Project</td>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>cost</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Project1</td>
    <td>Open</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Project2</td>
    <td>Open</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr style="border-bottom:1pt solid black;">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Project3</td>
    <td>Open</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Project4</td>
    <td>Pending</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Project6</td>
    <td>Pending</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr style="border-bottom:1pt solid black;">
    <td>6</td>
    <td>Project7</td>
    <td>Pending</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>Project7</td>
    <td>closed</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>Project8</td>
    <td>closed</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When the status changes I am required to add a bottom border to the previous row thereby grouping the table rows as per their status.

The table is sorted according to the status text and I need to apply bottom border to the row after which the status text is changing.
This will show the rows of the table grouped according to their status values.

I was thinking to have a one line selector instead of looping all over the table.

Thanks All.

Comment: Could you perhaps create an HTML fiddle of how you want it to look when the status changes?

Comment: In addition to @Locercus I want to know how the status changes.

Comment: @Zword I will second that. Do you have the option of a function call or do you have to .live it?

Comment: `grouping` is a broad term without some criteria and the expected output. A sort may qualify for example - but that isn't known.

Comment: @Locercus do edit anyway that it shows how the status changes and what u want onchange .If u update your question properly then your question will be reopened

Comment: I have edited my question,I need to add the border like in the example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473885/merge-empty-rows-with-text-row-using-jquery

Comment: @Zword the grid is sorted according to the status text I need to add border there after.

Comment: But You first need to sort table as per status and then you can merge.

Comment: @Innovation the table is sorted I m trying to find an efficient way to add borders

Comment: Ok I will post an answer from what I have understood aftr this question is reopened.

Comment: @Zword do I have to loop over the grid and compare the status texts or a nth selector like thing is possible like "select the last row having status Open/Closed/Pending".I am sorry if it is a silly question

Comment: @techie_28: If you clean-up your table a little bit, it would be easier for you. Add `thead` for the header row and `tbody` for the content rows. Then you could easily do this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ucedwhb0/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you structure your table a little bit, it would be easier for you. Add `thead` for the header row and `tbody` for the content rows. Then you could easily do this:

```
var last = null;
$("table tbody tr td:nth-child(3)").each(function() {
    if ((last) && (last != this.innerText)) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("group");
    } 
    last = this.innerText;
});
```

Assuming that your table is already sorted as indicated in your question, iterate over every 3<sup>rd</sup> `td` using `nth-child(3)`, comparing the `innerText` with the last.

***Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ucedwhb0/***

***Snippet***:

```js
function groupRows() {
    var last = null;
    $("table tbody tr td:nth-child(3)").each(function () {
        if ((last) && (last != this.innerText)) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("group");
        }
        last = this.innerText;
    });
}

groupRows();
```

```css
tr.group { border-top: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;" cellpadding="5" width="500px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Project</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>cost</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Project1</td>
            <td>Open</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Project2</td>
            <td>Open</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Project3</td>
            <td>Open</td>
            <td>200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Project4</td>
            <td>Pending</td>
            <td>200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Project6</td>
            <td>Pending</td>
            <td>200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Project7</td>
            <td>Pending</td>
            <td>200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>Project7</td>
            <td>closed</td>
            <td>200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>Project8</td>
            <td>closed</td>
            <td>200</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that will toggle a class on/off depending on row being last of that status. Thus when you resort on a staus change and call this it will also remove class on incorrect row(s)

```
 $('tr:gt(0)').each(function(){
    var $row =$(this),
        status = $(this).find('td').eq(2).text(),
        $nextRow=$row.next();
    if($nextRow.length){
        var isLastOfStatus = status !== $nextRow.find('td').eq(2).text();
        $row.toggleClass('divider', isLastOfStatus)
    }  
});
```

If you expect any white space added in markup within cells use `$.trim()` on the text values before comparing

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j9cat27j/)**</kbd>